# Share issue with script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this script I am using to make a copy of a sheet and then send me that copy thru email as a xslx file, if I have the sheet set for share to anyone with a link the script works great, but if I have it set to specific people it runs but gives a Value# instead of the data on the page. the page I am trying to send is a query importrange formula pulling the data on to the sheet. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
enter code herefunction emailExcel() {

    var mailTo, subject, body, id, sheetNum, sh, sourceSS, copySS, file, url,token, response;


    mailTo = 'elder1104@gmail.com';
    subject = 'subject';
    body = 'text_in_body';
    id = '1eI-p0nodA4zqP3fsxP5P6iR6gyvSIGRZDMaQSGkb2ds';
    sheetNum = 2;

    sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    copySS = sourceSS.copy('copy of ' + sourceSS.getName());
    sh = copySS.getSheets()[sheetNum];
    sh.getDataRange().setValues(sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues())
    copySS.getSheets()
    .forEach(function (sh, i) {
        if(i != sheetNum) copySS.deleteSheet(sh);
     })

    file = Drive.Files.get(copySS.getId());
    url = file.exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL];
    token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
     }
    });

    MailApp.sendEmail(mailTo, subject, body, {
    attachments: [response.getBlob()
        .setName('TESTING.xlsx')]
    });

   DriveApp.getFileById(copySS.getId()).setTrashed(true);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To share Drive file to specific people, try to add `setSharing(accessType, permissionType)` method given in [Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file).

As mentioned in [Working with enums](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#working_with_enums),

> the Drive service uses the enums **Access** and **Permission** to determine which users have access to a file or folder.

So to access file or folder in [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app), you should add the following enumerated types to determine users who can access a file or folder, besides any individual users who have been explicitly given access

- [Access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access)
- [Permission](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission)

It will really be helpful to try going through the given documentations.

Answer (score 0):

I took the easy way out and made a new spreadsheet and I am importing to that spreadsheet using a script, so now the new document just has data on it and is working perfectly now.